# Raspado web usando simple_html_dom.php para extraer coordenadas de mapa hecho con leaflet

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Que tal estoy trabajando con simple_html_dom.php para extraer datos de una pagina de inmobiliaria, hasta el momento solo tengo un problema para poder extraer los datos de los mapas por que están hechos con leaflet así que los datos están en un script hecho con JSON-LD. les paso el codigo.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"BuyAction","priceSpecification":{"@type":"PriceSpecification","price":"187000","priceCurrency":"USD"},"seller":{"@type":"RealEstateAgent","name":"Servial","image":"https://cdn1.infocasas.com.uy\/repo\/img\/5b4ed042a0c81_logoser.jpg","telephone":"4200088","logo":"https://cdn1.infocasas.com.uy\/repo\/img\/5b4ed042a0c81_logoser.jpg"},"object":{"@type":"SingleFamilyResidence","address":"final villalobos","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":"-17.36570000000000000000","longitude":"-66.13850000000000000000"}},"name":"Hermosa Casa En Venta De Dos Planta Inmediaciones Alto Mirador","url":"https://www.infocasas.com.bo\/hermosa-casa-en-venta-de-dos-planta-inmediaciones-alto-mirador\/185986507","image":"https://cdn1.infocasas.com.uy\/repo\/img\/136783_244035_122.jpg#HASTH","description":"187.000 \$us.- Hermosa casa en venta de dos plantas inmediaciones alto mirador, consta de:\nPLANTA BAJA: Escritorio, living, comedor, cocina con cajoneria alta y baja,despensa, ba\u00f1o de visita.\nPLANTA ALTA: 1 suite con vestidor y ropero empotrado, 2 dormitorios con roperos, sala de estar,ba\u00f1o.\nESTERIOR: garaje para 2 autos, jardin, parrillero, dependencias de empleada, deposito.\u00a0"}</script>
```

Este es el script donde se encuentra el código y como ven los datos de coordenadas están ahí dentro, ya intente varias formas pero no logro obtener ningún dato o me lanza errores de variables.

```
$url = 'https://www.infocasas.com.bo/'.$url;

$html = file_get_html($url);

$posts = $html->find('div[id=contenedor]');


 foreach ($posts as $post){


$titulo = $post->find('div[class=h1h] h1', 0);
$ficha = $post->find('div[class=ficha-tecnica] h2', 0);



$esp = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 0);
$cont = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 0);
$esp1 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 1);
$cont1 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 1);
$esp2 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 2);
$cont2 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 2);
$esp3 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 3);
$cont3 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 3);
$esp4 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 4);
$cont4 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 4);
$esp5 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 5);
$cont5 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 5);
$esp6 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 6);
$cont6 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 6);
$esp7 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 7);
$cont7 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 7);
$esp8 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 8);
$cont8 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 8);
$esp9 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 9);
$cont9 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 9);
$esp10 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 10);
$cont10 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 10);
$esp11 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 11);
$cont11 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 11);
$esp12 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 12);
$cont12 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 12);
$esp13 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 13);
$cont13 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 13);
$esp14 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 14);
$cont14 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 14);
$esp15 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 15);
$cont15 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 15);
$esp16 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 16);
$cont16 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 16);
$esp17 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 17);
$cont17 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 17);
$esp18 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 18);
$cont18 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 18);
$esp19 = $post->find('div[class=lista] p', 19);
$cont19 = $post->find('div[class=lista] div', 19);



$telefono = $post->find('div[class=centerHolder] div', 0);

$descripcion = $post->find('div[id=descripcion] h2', 0);
```

Este es parte del código que estoy utilizando para hacer la extracción de datos, trate utilizando los mismos métodos para el script pero no obtengo nada. Alguna sugerencia me vendría de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Viendo que es un json por qué no accedes primero a la etiqueta Script con `$post->find('script');` seguramente haya más de una etiqueta Script tendrás que averiguar cual es. Luego puedes obtener el contenido, el json en cuestión, y le haces un `json_decode()`. Luego es cuestión de acceder al elemento que necesites.

Comment: Utilice este $script = $post->find('script[type=application/ld+json]', 0);
 $json = json_decode($script->innertext, true); no me mostro ningun error pero cuando use  echo para que me muestre no hay nada..  o estoy cometiendo algun error.